# Custom delegate to use pushViewController from UIView class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates

I am trying to pushViewController from UIView class thus have used custom delegate to use pushViewController. Below is error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'HomeCategCollectionView' with no arguments
```

Below is code:

```
// ViewController

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let viewHomeCategories = HomeCategCollectionView() // here error comes
    viewHomeCateg.delegate = self
}

// UIView class

private func showCategDetails(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    delegate?.pushToListingButton()

}
```

Update: HomeCategCollectionView

```
class HomeCategCollectionViewModel {
var categViewVMs: [HomeCategCellViewModel]?

init(categModels: [GVMHomeCateg]?) {
    self.categViewVMs = categModels?.map({
        HomeCategCellViewModel(categ: $0)
    })
}
}

protocol ListingDelegate : class {
    func pushToListingButton()
}


class HomeCategCollectionView: UIView {

// MARK: Initialization and view setup

init(categViewModel: HomeCategCollectionViewModel?) {
    self.viewModel = categViewModel
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setup()
}
}
```

Please guide. Hope I made my query clear, if not feel free to ask.
Thank you

Comment: what is HomeCategCollectionView ? Error says you cant initialise it without passing the required parameters

Comment: It is a class of UIView

Comment: Please add the code for `HomeCategCollectionView` so we can see its initializer

Comment: The error means what it says, you have to use one of the designated initializers, either `init(categViewModel:` or `init?(coder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initializer of `HomeCategCollectionView` is `init(categViewModel: HomeCategCollectionViewModel?)` so you need to call it with all parameters:

```
// ViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let data: [GVMHomeCateg] = // Your data
    let viewModel = HomeCategCollectionViewModel(categModels: data)
    let viewHomeCategories = HomeCategCollectionView(categViewModel: viewModel)
    viewHomeCateg.delegate = self
}
```

Or

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let viewHomeCategories = HomeCategCollectionView(categViewModel: nil)
    viewHomeCateg.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your `HomeCategCollectionView` with all required parameters, so in this case `categViewModel` or `coder`. The following would work.

```
let viewHomeCategories = HomeCategCollectionView(categViewModel: nil)
```

Ideally of course you don't pass `nil` but an instance of the view model that should be used.